# VIM - Move through wrapped lines (in insert mode)

Tags: vim

I'm not a fan of 80(or 72) characters pr. line followed by a line-break even if your VIM inserts the line-break itself - you'll easily run into inconsistency problems when editing that line of text afterwards. Otherwise I have nothing against the editor, but somehow editing text as I do in a GUI editor makes me sleep better at night.

So, I discovered that the reason for the line breaks was primarily due to inability to move through softly wrapped lines, and hence I found this article: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Move_through_wrapped_lines which works, but I'm looking for a solution that would work in insert-mode as well as edit-mode.

P.S. I'm probably a newbie at VIM :)

Comment: Insert mode is "edit" mode.  Adding those imap lines to your .vimrc should do exactly what you want.  Alternatively, add `set nowrap` to stop Vim from softwrapping your lines.  (It isn't adding newlines unless you set `textwidth`.)

Comment: The lines `imap <Down> <C-o>gj` and `imap <Up> <C-o>gk` should work in insert mode.

Comment: The latter does not work (for me at least).

Answer (score 4):

Why would you need to move through wrapped lines in insert mode? You'd better move through such lines in command mode with `gj` and `gk` and when you need to edit something, press `i`, edit and go out of insert mode.
The less time you'll be spending in insert mode, the better.

Answer (score 2):

```
imap <Down> <C-o>gj
```

and

```
imap <Up> <C-o>gk
```

works for me.

My configuration is as follows:

```
vmap <silent> <Right> l
vmap <silent> <Left> h
vmap <silent> <Up> gk
vmap <silent> <Down> gj
nmap <silent> <Right> l
nmap <silent> <Left> h
nmap <silent> <Up> gk
nmap <silent> <Down> gj
imap <silent> <Up> <C-o>gk
imap <silent> <Down> <C-o>gj
```

My complete configuration is here:

https://github.com/Waxolunist/vimconf